# Azure custom policy B2c after completing forgot password how to redirect to signup page?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-policy

In my sign-up form, I have a forgot password link if the user clicks on that link forgot password flow will start and the user is able to change his password but it's redirecting to the website's home page.

Explanation of issue:

1. user opens the site [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)
2. Clicks on signup/signin button.
3. Redirects to B2c signup form there we have forgotten password link
4. User clicks forgot password then email validation screen will come after validation user is able to change the password but redirected to [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)
   I want users should be able to redirect to the signup/sign-in page mainly step 3 could you please guide me on this?

- Code:
  SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail is my default userjourney
  in step 3 forgotpassword:

[image]

- Orchestration order 3:

```xml
    
     <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                  <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <JourneyList>
                <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
              </JourneyList>
            </OrchestrationStep>
    
    Complete Userjourney lines
    
     <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail">
          <OrchestrationSteps>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="signuporsignin-phone-email">
              <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninPhoneEmailExchange" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithEmail" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithPhone" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ChangePhoneNumber" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LinkedInExchange" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
              </ClaimsProviderSelections>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Phone-Email" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithPhone" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="ChangePhoneNumber" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneInputPage-ChangePhoneNumberClaimsProviderSelection" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LinkedInExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LinkedIn-OAuth2" />
                <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                  <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <JourneyList>
                <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
              </JourneyList>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isEmailSignUp</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isPhoneSignUp</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isEmailSignUp</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>isPhoneSignUp</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                  <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <JourneyList>
                <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="SignInWithPhoneOrEmail" />
              </JourneyList>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- -test changes//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
            <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
            <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
              This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
              using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
            <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
              in the token. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                  <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
                  <Value>hasFullProfile</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
                 from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
                 (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- - test changes/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                  <Value>isChangePhoneNumber</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <JourneyList>
                <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="ChangePhoneNumber" />
              </JourneyList>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
          </OrchestrationSteps>
          <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
        </UserJourney>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used [Transfer subjourney](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/subjourneys#example-scenarios). Have you tried your flow with Call subjourney? Once **Call** subjourney ends the journey that called it continues to execute. If that doesn't help then try to cut your yourney into reusable set of subjourneys and call the "main" flow from within the PasswordReset journey. Don't forget to perform NullClaim claims transformation on the isPasswordReset claim to avoid neverending loop.